# uWSGI cannot auto create folder in /tmp

Tags: uwsgi

I have a uwsgiconfig.yaml like this

```
socket: /tmp/uwsgi/myapp/socket
chmod-socket: 666
```

But this doesn't work because there is no folder `uwsgi` or `myapp` in `/tmp`.

If I'm doing it like this, it works

```
socket: /tmp/uwsgi.myapp.socket
chmod-socket: 666
```

So why can not `uWSGI` just create the file by the full path? Or what should I do, what's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common UNIX pattern/best practice. Even mkdir does not do it without a proper flag.

If you want to create the directory tree you can use uWSGI hooks:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Hooks.html

```
if-not-dir = /tmp/uwsgi/
 hook-asap = mkdir:/tmp/uwsgi/
end-if =
```

or

```
exec-asap = mkdir -p /tmp/uwsgi/myapp
```